# Python Dictionary to R session

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I have a python dictionary and want to import it in R.

> d = {'X1':[[1,2,3], [10,20]], 'X2':[4,5,6,7]}

In "R" I want it as

```
> d
$X1
$X1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$X1[[2]]
[1] 10 20


$X2
[1] 4 5 6 7
```

How can I export/save the python dictionary and read it in R?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use JSON: [Importing data from a JSON file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617600/importing-data-from-a-json-file-into-r)
2. Use RPY2: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/
3. Use HDF Format: [Does anyone have experience opening hdf files in R (Windows OS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687913/does-anyone-have-experience-opening-hdf-files-in-r-windows-os)

Answer (score 1):

To read it from an R session you can save your dictionary in [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) format (maybe you will need to install an R library to decode it, like `jsonlite` or `rjson`). 
Otherwise, write it in a table that you can load with `read.table`, such as CSV format.