# Unable to open HDF5 into R

Tags: r

I have successfully loaded in the `rhdf5` package, but am unable to open the file and create an R data frame. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687913/does-anyone-have-experience-opening-hdf-files-in-r-windows-os) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725609/r-and-hdf5-troubles) and [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/rhdf5/inst/doc/rhdf5.pdf) but am still unclear. I have also tried the `hdfdump` but that results in error.

How do I read in the HDF5 file? I know I want all of the columns and do not need to group, but rather would like one full data frame. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded file "h5ex_t_string.h5" at random from [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/files/exbyapi/) to use as an example.

The way to read a .h5 file is the following:

```
library(rhdf5)   #load library
h5ls("h5ex_t_string.h5")  #this will show you the name to use below in the argument

> h5ls("h5ex_t_string.h5")
  group name       otype dclass dim
0     /  DS1 H5I_DATASET STRING   4   #so the name is DS1

D = h5read("h5ex_t_string.h5",name='DS1') #use the filename and the name to read file

> D   #Weird message in the file but I randomly downloaded it 
[1] "Parting" "is such" "sweet  " "sorrow."
```

The h5read function returns an array which you can then convert into a data.frame if you like

```
> a<-data.frame(D)
> a
        D
1 Parting
2 is such
3 sweet  
4 sorrow.
```